# spyOn not working on a dependency in Angular 7 unit tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spy, angular-test

I have a component that depends on **SearchAttributeService**. There is a method called **searchAttributeValidation** service that returns a **Subject**. I am subscribing to that subject like this:

```
  attributeSearchValidation(): void {
    this._searchAttributeService.searchAttributeValidation.subscribe((value: string) => {
      if (value === this._searchAttributeService.emptyAttributeSearchData) {
        this.searchAttributeIndicator = true;
      } else if (value === this._searchAttributeService.clearEmptyAttributeSearchDataValidation) {
        this.searchAttributeIndicator = false;
    });
  }

get searchAttributeValidation(): Subject<string> {
   return this.searchAttributeValidationSubject;
}
```

I am trying to test this method like this:

```
  searchAttributeService = TestBed.get(SearchAttributeService);
  let spy = spyOn(searchAttributeService, 'searchAttributeValidation').and.returnValue(of('EMPTY-DATA'));
  component.attributeSearchValidation();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.searchAttributeIndicator).toBeTruthy();
```

It does not call the **searchAttributeValidation** method at all during the test. I even provided the service **TestBed.configureTestingModule({**

The test fails with the message: **Expected spy searchAttributeValidation to have been called.**

Where am I going wrong?? Spent a whole day on it, but, couldn't figure out the issue?

Comment: what is the error that you are receiving in the log?

Comment: @AjayReddy Expected spy searchAttributeValidation to have been called.

Comment: 'searchAttributeValidation' is an observable object and not a method. 'spyOn' can be used for methods and not for objects.

Comment: @AshishPatel searchAttributeValidation is a getter method that returns an observable
  get searchAttributeValidation(): Subject<string> {
    return this.searchAttributeValidationSubject;
  }

Comment: you are mocking the service and then expecting the actual service method to get called....instead you need to check the test for the values inside the subscribe method like expect(searchAttributeIndicator).toBeTruthy()...etc

Comment: @AjayReddy I am getting Expected spy searchAttributeValidation to have been called. message, means I am not able to call the mock itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spyOn is for methods but you are accessing a property, if it was a method you would be accessing it like

```
this._searchAttributeService.searchAttributeValidation().subscribe
```

with the call () paramaters.

If it is a getter property then use spyOnProperty or if it is an instance property then reassign it.

```
searchAttributeService.searchAttributeValidation = of('EMPTY-DATA');
```

and get rid of the expect to have been called.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it works not. Your explanation was spot-on.